# Can one rails application connect to multiple resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I using single rails application and I like to connect multiple resque to publish a message to multiple resque queues 
I am using [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) gem but I not see any way to configure multiple resque can someone help me on this what configuration need to do on that case.

Comment: what do you mean with multiple resque? multiple resque servers/nodes?

Comment: Do you mean multiple queues?

Comment: yes multiple resque servers/nodes